# Re-read the notes at the end of an installation using macports

Tags: macos, macports

In many cases, when installing a port using macports there are some messages showing up during the process. Is it possible to regenerate/see these messages after the installation of the port has finished?

Answer (score 3):

To see the notes for just the port foo:

```
port notes foo
```

To see the notes for all the dependencies needed by foo:

```
port notes rdepof:foo
```

Craig